# Flutter window_manager fullscreen embedded webview_windows not displaying fullscreen

Tags: flutter, webview, fullscreen, desktop-application, window-managers

In Flutter, I have been able to make a windows desktop application fullscreen with the use of https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager.git

In this application, I want the entire screen to display the contents of a website.  Right now I am using webview_windows to do this. And it does display the webpage I am pointing to, but the last 3 rows of pixels on my monitor are not showing the webpage. instead, it is showing the background color of the Flutter app.

To demo what I mean, here is a screenshot of what the app currently looks like:
[image]

Also here is a close up of the bottom of the app:
[image]

The green is coming from the embedded website and the red, is coming from the flutter backgroundColor

This is my current pubspec.yaml:

```
name: test
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  window_manager:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager.git
      ref: main
  webview_windows: ^0.2.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

And this is my current main.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';
import 'package:webview_windows/webview_windows.dart';

void main() async {
  // go fullscreen
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Must add this line.
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();
  
  WindowOptions windowOptions = const WindowOptions(
    //size: Size(1920, 1080),
    center: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    skipTaskbar: false,
    titleBarStyle: TitleBarStyle.hidden,
  );
    windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
      await windowManager.setFullScreen(true);
      await windowManager.show();
      await windowManager.focus();
  });

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
} 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ExampleBrowser()
    );
  }
}

class ExampleBrowser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ExampleBrowser> createState() => _ExampleBrowser();
}

class _ExampleBrowser extends State<ExampleBrowser> {
  LoadingState waitingState = LoadingState.loading;
  final _controller = WebviewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    try {
      await _controller.initialize();
      await _controller.setBackgroundColor(Colors.transparent);
      await _controller.setPopupWindowPolicy(WebviewPopupWindowPolicy.deny);
      await _controller.loadUrl('https://abbashouse.net/demo/test.html');

      _controller.loadingState.listen((event) => { 
        setState(() {
          waitingState = event;
        })
      });

      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {});
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
  
  Widget compositeView() {
    return (waitingState == LoadingState.navigationCompleted) 
      ? Scaffold(
        body: Webview( _controller, width:1920.0, height:1080.0 ) 
      )
      : Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return compositeView();
  }

}
```

here is what it looks like when i hard code the hight of the webview to 200.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here the size has been specified

```
Scaffold(
        body: Webview( _controller, width:1920.0, height:1080.0 ) 
      )
```

You can try adding the same size as device

```dart
Scaffold(
        body: Webview( _controller, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) 
      )
```

You can also create a SizedBox of screen size and add the WebView to it

```dart
Scaffold (
 body :SizedBox(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
 child: WebView(),
 )
)
```

Comment: Okay I tried your suggestion, but it is not working.  I even tried to overset the height to 1083.0 and much higher than that, and it still is showing 3 rows of red pixels at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Maybe the website itself is small try someother website once please

Comment: Okay, I tried another site, and its doing the same thing.

Comment: Okay, i tried your updated answer, and im still seeing the red at the bottom.  I really think there is a bug in webview_windows

Comment: Not sure. Can you give a fixed height like 200 or 300 and see if you still get the redline

Comment: Okay yes, when i set a fixed hight of 200, it is only showing the first 200 pixels high of the embedded website, then the rest is white, but the last 3 rows of pixels are still red. See new screenshot i placed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug within the window_manager plugin. It has been fixed (hopefully [PR#359](https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager/pull/359) or [PR#367](https://github.com/leanflutter/window_manager/pull/367). Please update to the latest version (0.3.6) and see if it's fixed.